# Python - Regex match last key/value into dictionary string

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I read this dictionary from a file as a string:

```
string = '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}'
```

I don't know which values key1 and key2 can assume, I need to access the value of the last pair written on the string (in this case 'value2'). So converting it into a python dictionary is out of the question since it would probably change the order.

I've tried something like:

```
value = re.search(r'"(.*?)":"(.*?)"', string)
```

But I don't know how to access the .group(2) of the last match.

Comment: Can't you try just `eval()` ?

Comment: [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Comment: why should the order matter? why isn't this data coming in as a list?

Comment: See the accepted answer at the question I marked as a dupe, I think it's much saner than a regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this :

```
import re
output = re.findall(".*\"[a-zA-Z0-9]+\"[\w]*:[\w]*\"(.+)\"[\w]*}", string)
```

Output :

```
>>> re.findall(".*\"[a-zA-Z0-9]+\"[\w]*:[\w]*\"(.+)\"[\w]*}", string)
['value2']
```